# C++ cross platform mobile framework only for the UI

Tags: c++, c, mobile, user-interface, cross-platform

I decided that for me it's convenient to code my app in C++ since this is the right language when having a cross platform solution in mind.

The problem is that the UI frameeworks for each platform are really tricky to handle and they require a considerable amount of time to create even the simplest UI framework; in the UI part I'm also putting the multi-touch gesture, the virtual buttons, the text-area inputs, and all the basic stuff that can receive and handle user input.

Now most of this UI are based on HTML5, and basically all the apps end up having the same "cool" look, never the less this HTML5 solutions are not for me because i'm looking for a C/C++ solution.

What libraries i can consider if i'm looking for a mobile cross platform UI library in C/C++ or that can be interfaced with C/C++ code ?

With cross platform i mean at least a support for iOS and Android.

Comment: you are better off dropping the "C++" requirement, and looking for cross platform programming tools for mobile apps.   This question isn't stackoverflow compatible, because you are polling the community

Answer (score 3):

Cross mobile is slightly impossible for now. Why not try to code everything in html5? And write platform specific C++ code separately for multiple mobile platforms?

Also look at Corona SDK (which I have heard, has better support).

Edit:

http://www.mosync.com/ seems like another viable option. This also allows you to mix html5 and C++

Comment: how i can interface html5 and C++ ? I'm willing to sacrifice performances with HTML5, the important thing is that i can interface the 2 parts.

Comment: I'm taking a look at it but i think it's unusable for Android, the SDK it's not available for Linux, so even if it will support Android it will surely offer some big trouble down the road. Also i'm not using Windows or Mac for now and i would like to avoid them as much as i can.

Comment: @guz its available for Android. But the SDK isn't for Linux. But you can always install a windows copy on a virtual machine for your development if it isn't much of a problem. Some solutions need change-of-os. If you were going to code for iOS you would've probably needed to have an Apple anyway. Just a thought.

Comment: yes, but the only OS that offers full support for Android is a GNU/linux distribution, all the other one are just pure troubles. The Apple thing is something that i want to think about it, i would like to re-use my work, but it will depends on what will be the Apple attitude in the future. If this SDK says that supports Android without being published under Linux, it doesn't support Android, it will surely be some kind of bad porting full of bugs.

Comment: @guz I disagree. I code for Android on Windows and all my apps work(exactly like I had intended it to). I use JDK and AndroidSDK though(with Eclipse). If you're looking at NDT I would rather stick with MoSync for this.

Comment: @guz. I don't think you need to have Linux as your host machine to develop Android apps. Even though Android is essentially Linux, it doesn't mean that you need to have Linux as the host. You can have Windows or even Mac OS as your desktop or laptop machine to develop Android apps.

Answer (score 2):

For now, the most popular approaches to cross-mobile-platform development are:

- Logic in C++, UI separately for each platform in the appropriate language
- Mono, which is to say .NET/C#
- HTML-based frameworks, (PhoneGap, Appcelerator)

Neither of those fits all of your requirements. Decide which is more important - maximum code reuse? C++?

Specifically for UI, that's the hardest part to abstract away. Cross-platform GUI libraries (Qt, Swing) tend to aim for the lowest common denominator, and apps end up looking ugly on all of the supported platforms.